# What causes OpenJPA logging "Warn: "it.aaa.bbb.input" is being mapped with a handler that may not be able to store values over 4000 bytes/chars long"

Tags: java, jpa

I'm working with OpenJPA 2.2.3-SNAPSHOT on Oracle JDBC driver 11.1.0.7.0-Production.
I get this strange error and I want to be sure it is not a real problem.
What does it mean ?
Thanks

I checked for some limits in entity structures, but I found none.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle stores a string default in a varchar2 datatype. There is a limit of 4000 bytes on the varchar2 datatype. See https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/datatype-limits.html#GUID-963C79C9-9303-49FE-8F2D-C8AAF04D3095.

With the @Column(length = n) annotation on your attributes you can define the size of your varchar2 column in the database.

With the @Lob annotation you can store your string in a lob column in your database which can be larger than 4000 bytes.